# Using scanner in java switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I want to use scanner to make a user use a number in the switch code I wrote:

```
public class NewClass1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner abd=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int k = 5;
        int k = i.nextInt();
        switch (k) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("You chosed 0");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("You chosed 1");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("You chosed 3");
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println("You chosed 9");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter something is in the list, Which is: 0,1,3,9.");
                break;
        }
}
```

I think there's something wrong or missing in my code, I will appreciate the help.

Comment: Any error, you are getting?

Comment: Yes,  int k=i.nextInt();

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I removed it but it only prints

Comment: Enter a number
Please enter something is in the list, Which is: 0,1,3,9.

Comment: What is `i` in `int k=i.nextInt();` ?

Comment: @Abdulaziz: Please put the additional informations in your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will not even compile..

```
int k = 5;
int k=i.nextInt(); // same variable already define in the scope.
```

Next point is your referring `i`, But your Scanner is initialize as `abd`. Remove line `int k = 5` and you should change your code to

```
  int k = abd.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your scanner is named `abd`, but you call `i.nextInt()`. That is the problem.

**EDIT**

```
int k = 5;
k = abd.nextInt();
```

Comment: so the solution is   int k=abd.nextInt(); ?

Comment: I edited my answer. Check it.